# String with timestamp changing in airflow dag

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to use the datetime as a unique
identifier for a s3 folder that I create in an airflow dag.
However, the datetime string seems to be changing despite
no work on my part. Does anyone know why?

```
dag.py
import utility
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging

folder = utility.get_id()

def print_params_fn(**kwargs):
    logging.info(kwargs)
    return None


DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}
with DAG(
        dag_id='mydag',
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        max_active_runs=1,
        schedule_interval='0 17 * * *',
        catchup=False) as dag:
step1 = PythonOperator(task_id='step1', python_callable=utility.do_something,
                op_kwargs={'read_dir': folder})

step2 = PythonOperator(task_id='step2', python_callable=utility.do_something,
                op_kwargs={'read_dir': folder})

print_params0 = PythonOperator(task_id="print_params0",
                                  python_callable=print_params_fn,
                                  provide_context=True,
                                  op_kwargs={'folder_name': folder})

print_params = PythonOperator(task_id="print_params",
                                  python_callable=print_params_fn,
                                  provide_context=True,
                                  op_kwargs={'folder_name': folder})


print_params0 >> step1 >> print_params >> step2
```

```
utility.py
import os
from datetime import datetime
def get_id():
    # current date and time
    now = datetime.now()
    return str(int(datetime.timestamp(now)))

def do_something(read_dir):
    print('dir exists{}'.format(os.path.exists()))
    return None
```

When I log folder to the airflow logs, before node 1 I see:
1608239870, but when I log the folder to the airflow logs before node 2,
I see 1608239840.

I expect the folder variable to stay constant, but for some reason they are changing.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `get_id()` to create a unique identifier for the folder.
It's better to use the DAG `execution_date`.
You can do:

```
op_kwargs={'read_dir': {{ execution_date.int_timestamp }}}
```

Comment: where do I import execution_date from? I don't see any package in airflow forit

Comment: nevermind, it's jinja so I think you just need quotation marks around the braces